# Paypal Redirect

Tags: api, paypal

I am working on paypal. I am redirecting it to

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. 
When i click the pay now button, it goes to another link giving 3 options:

1. Redirect to your site
2. Go to PayPal account overview
3. Add funds from your bank

When I click first link then it takes to my site.

When I click the pay now button and payment is confirmed, I dont want to go to this page

which gives these options. I want directly to go to my site.
How is that possible?
Please help

Comment: This should be posted on Stack Overflow instead (making it clear it's an API programming question, that's not immediately apparent on first read).  Also, no you can't do this...think about the user, if you're not showing them a confirmation they're confused as to *if* they paid or not, that's very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the seller you can actually set your website payment preference on your paypal account so that any payments made via your buy button it will be automatically redirected to your site (without seeing page that you said above).

- Login to your paypal account (as seller)
- Go to profile > My selling tools
- Find "Website Preference" section, click `Update`
- Set the `Auto Return:` option to `ON`
- Fill `Return URL` with valid URL (URL that will be used to redirect your customers upon payment completion)
- Save

Comment: Is this also for sanbox testing accounts as i am using https://www.sandbox.paypal.com for transaction?

I have login into https://developer.paypal.com with an email address. Here when I click on profile it just takes me to update my info e.g name.
I have made test account for seller here. It is used for transactions but not to login as a seller.
How will I login as seller account and on which site?
Thankyou for your help.

Comment: @user1891283 Sorry for late reply. Sure you're welcome. You may mark this as answer so this may useful to others having similar problem.